# Is there any way to have IntelliJ automatically evaluate an expression when a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to run a ton of unit tests in the IntelliJ debugger and have them all stop at the same breakpoint. When each unit test stops there, I will do the following:

- Right click and select "Evaluate Expression..."
- Enter the code fragment `new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myObject)` and click Evaluate
- Copy the value of the result

Is there any way to have that expression evaluated automatically when it hits the breakpoint, so I don't have to right-click and open the "Evaluate" window and paste in the code and click the Evaluate button every single time?

Comment: You can use logging breakpoint and log the evaluated expression in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a conditional breakpoint, where code is part of the condition.

Just right-click the breakpoint and specify Condition.

You only need to simply add `return false` in the end of the code so that the condition evaluates to false, and thus breakpoint doesn't stop execution (or `return true` if you actually want it to stop).

Example:
[image]

When ran in Debug, this outputs:

```
Debug 0
Hello
Debug 1
Hello
Debug 2
Hello
Debug 3
Hello
Debug 4
Hello
Debug 5
Hello
Debug 6
Hello
Debug 7
Hello
Debug 8
Hello
Debug 9
Hello
```

P.S. Here's a code to put stuff into clipboard with Java:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.defaultToolkit.systemClipboard.setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(contentToCopy.toString()), null)
```

Put this into the breakpoint Condition, replace `contentToCopy` with the stuff that you need to get onto clipboard, append `return false` - and it's done.

P.P.S. Here, I assume this should be it:

```
java.awt.Toolkit.defaultToolkit.systemClipboard.setContents(new java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection(new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myObject)), null); return false
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not that much better, because I have to go to the console, and scroll and find the beginning of the log containing the value I want (since the value is several hundred lines long), and then copy it. If there's a way to just quickly "Copy Value" in IntelliJ, that would be ideal.

Comment: You can just use Java's ability to put stuff onto the clipboard if that's the end goal. The issue is, if code hits this breakpoint twice - you're only getting the latest value. If that's ok with you, I can add copy code to the answer - no problem. P.S. Done!

Comment: Did it work for you?